# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code - Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have the following C# classes:

```
public class Locales
{
    public Region region { get; set; }
    public Buttons buttons { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public Center center { get; set; }
    public East east { get; set; }
}

public class Center
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class East
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Buttons
{
    public string save { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Labels labels { get; set; }
}

public class Labels
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string chooseLocale { get; set; }
}
```

To sum up, Locales has Region, Buttons and Fields. Region has Center and East. Center and East have property title. Fields has Labels which has properties firstName, lastName and chooseLocale.

In a method (called GetLocale) I have the following code:

```
Locale englishLang = new Locale(); 
englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";
englishLang.region.east.title = "East Region - Form";
englishLang.buttons.save = "Save";
englishLang.fields.labels.firstName = "First Name";
englishLang.fields.labels.lastName = "Last Name";
englishLang.fields.labels.chooseLocale = "Choose Your Locale";
```

When I run the code, a "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" is thrown at the line :  `englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";`

Am I doing something wrong in the way I have set the properties title, save, firstName, lastName and chooseLocale?
I tried adding the following block of code after `Locale englishLang = new Locale();` and before `englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";` but I still get the error message.

```
Region region = new Region();
Center center = new Center();
East east = new East();
Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
Fields fields = new Fields();
Labels labels = new Labels();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the point of this code is to support different languages, I'd recommend to have a look at Resources in the .Net framework.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Locales` object never instantiates its properties, nor does the consuming code instantiate them.  As reference types, the properties in that class have a default value of `null`.  So when you do this:

```
Locale englishLang = new Locale();
```

The following values are `null`:

```
englishLang.region
englishLang.buttons
englishLang.fields
```

Thus, you'll receive a `NullReferenceException` if you try to de-reference those fields, like you do here:

```
englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";
```

That line of code attempts to de-reference `englishLang.region` by referring to its `center` property.  But `region` is `null` because it hasn't been instantiated yet.

The best place to instantiate those in the case of these DTO classes would probably be in their constructors.  Something like this:

```
public class Locales
{
    public Region region { get; set; }
    public Buttons buttons { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }

    public Locales()
    {
        region = new Region();
        buttons = new Buttons();
        fields = new Fields();
    }
}
```

That way consuming code doesn't have to do this manually each time, the fields are automatically instantiated by the constructor any time you create an instance of `Locales`.  Naturally, you'll want to repeat this same pattern for your other objects.

Comment: +1 - I too feel that it's a good practice to have a class that aggregates other classes instantiate them rather than burdening the class consumer with that task.

Answer (score 5):

You have to instantiate each and every object:

```
Locale englishLang = new Locale(); 
englishLang.region = new Region();
englishLang.region.center = new Center();
englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";
```

and so on...

Or you can instantiate the dependent objects in the constructor of the parent class.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize the properties/sub properties before assigning values:

```
Locale englishLang = new Locale(); 
englishLang.region = new Region();
englishLang.region.center = new Center();
englishLang.region.center.title = "Center Region";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using automatic properties, and by default they return `null` for reference types. You need to initialize the properties, probably in the constructor:

```
public class Locales
{
    public Locales()
    {
        this.region =  new Region();
        this.buttons = new Buttons();
        this.fields = new Fields();
    }

    public Region region { get; set; }
    public Buttons buttons { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}
```

You'll also need to add similar code to the other classes.